# Getting the state and city on the basis of country name in android

Tags: android, location

Is there any way available in android through which I get the the city list on the basis of the state and state list on the basis of country .

Thanks in advance

eg :
             India
             madhya pradesh(list of all states)
             jabalpur(list of all cities)

I tried through the google places api
[google places api](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-autocompletetextview-with-google-places-autocomplete-api/)

Comment: Show us whatever you have tried!

Comment: What do you have tried so far? No code, No answer!

Comment: i tried through the google places api .i mentioned link in the post. But i need seperate list .like locale gives country list like that.